# How to use Webpacker in Rails 5.2.2?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, webpack, ruby-on-rails-5, webpacker

I'm starting to learn to use React with Rails. In application.html.erb I replaced

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

with

```
<%= javascript_pack_tag    'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

How do I require everything from the /assets/javascripts/application.js file?

```
//= require rails-ujs
//= require activestorage
//= require turbolinks
//= require cookies_eu
//= require_tree .
//= require jquery3
//= require popper
//= require bootstrap
```

Do I import them all at the beginning of the /javascript/packs/application.js file?

Answer (score -1):

Based on a tutorial I watched, I can just keep also the:

```
 <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

Then everything will be loaded, though not via Webpack.